# Really pink Chinese BBQ Pork (Char Siu): Safe to eat?

Tags: food-safety, meat, pork

I know Chinese BBQ Pork is definitely red/pink on the outside extending into the meat somewhat, and I know that the USDA now says that pink pork is safe to eat (another taboo from my youth gone) - but is *this* package safe?  I've seen pink Chinese BBQ pork but not really *this* pink all the way through.  Normal or not?

[image: Chinese BBQ Pork, pink all the way through]

Comment: How was it made? Or where did you buy it from?

Comment: @AnastasiaZendaya -  Bought it packaged from a store (still in its shrinkwrap, as photographed), claimed to be made by that store's deli/meat dept.

Comment: There is no way we can tell you if this is safe or not, based on the information provided. Additionally, color is not a useful indicator, especially if a cure was added, which is entirely possible. Whether or not this particular product is "normal", would also require more information...and someone with local knowledge.

Comment: @davidbak Okay... what is the name of the store?

Comment: @moscafj - so, I could ask if they "cure" it in some way?

Comment: ...you could...I would still not be comfortable stating whether or not the product is safe, based on a photo and limited description provided.

Comment: Have you bought char siu in this store before? Or if others also look that pink? Coz the outside is really bright red.. not sure what kind of food coloring. But I heard that the inside pink might be the case that the pork has been frozen for a long time before cooking.

Answer (score -2):

Chinese char siu is commonly colored with red food coloring. It should be safe to eat.

Comment: The pink color there is clearly not the result of red food coloring (which has dyed the outer bits but not penetrated very far).